# search with apostrophe string in mongo

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, regexp-replace

I have a string store in the database "Slater's Deli" I want to query when users search slaters that time also that result come. Now I handle with the help of regex like if user type slater that time result showing and when user type slater's that time also shows. But when user type slaters no result is found. That is the query which I am using now:-

```
 db.venues.find({"venue.name" : { $regex: "Slaters",$options:'is'}}, {"venue" :1}).pretty();
```

I want results for slaters also means when user type slaters that string "Slater's Deli" come

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can do something like: db.venues.find({ "venue.name": {
    "$regex": "slater'?s?", "$options": "i"}}, {"venue": 1}), and add the " '?s? " to any word of the name in the code...